# The request generates the "key1", "key2" in Swagger

Tags: java, json, web-services, swagger

I have the sample request as given below. May I know how to make the request generates the `key1`, `key2`, etc. in `JSON Swagger`? As it seems like not a predefined object from the `swagger` file.

```html
Sample request:
{
    "products": {
          "key1": {
                    "price": 99.146564,
                    "currencyPair": "USD-MYR",
                    "decimalPlace": 2
                  },
          "key2": {
                    "price": 86.1571,
                    "currencyPair": "USD-IDR"
                  },
          "key3": {
                    "price": 722.45654,
                    "currencyPair": "USD-ZNH"
                  }
           }
}
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.